# Outlook : Add-in Position to preview panel

Tags: outlook-addin

I am working on add Office CustomTaskPane to my outlook. My target is to set this Pane at bottom of my mail preview. I am able to set at bottom but it show entire bottom body of outlook instead only to Reading Pane (email preview).

**My code as below:**

```
Private CTP As Office.CustomTaskPane
CTP = m_CTP.CreateCTP(CTP_PROGID, CTP_TITLE, objExplWrap.Explorer) 'm_olExplorer
'CTP.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange
CTP.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionBottom
CTP.Visible = False
```

**What it show:**

[image]

**What I have to show (Requirement):**

[image]